# how to get idletime of set item in redis

Tags: redis

I know you can get the idletime of a key in redis to get the rough amount of time since an operation has been performed on that key.

I want to do the same thing for a key in a set.

So I have:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> smembers celery_tasks
1) "c997f588daa54c07a9bf7c764f08714cEnter Account Number..."
```

I can get the idletime of celery_tasks, but I want to get the idletime of "c997f588daa54c07a9bf7c764f08714cEnter Account Number..."

Is there a way to do this?  Does redis support this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope - the elements in lists and members in sorted and regular sets have no meta data of their own, only key-level idletime is accounted.